# OWL Carousel is not working

Tags: jquery

here is my code html code..

```
<div class="sliderImgs">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="img/man.jpg" alt="" >
    <img src="img/slider.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

owl carousel jquery

```
$('.sliderImgs').owlCarousel({
        navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed : 300,
        paginationSpeed : 400,
        singleItem:true,
        autoPlay: 1000
    });
```

and the css

```
.sliderImgs img{display:block;width:100%;height:auto;}
```

Comment: u are missing dot in css .sliderImgs img{display:block;width:100%;height:auto;}

Comment: Did you include the jquery library can you please post ALL of your code not just this bit.

Comment: sorry bhavik but dot is there... but still not working.

Comment: yes kevin i have included both jQuery and owl carousel library.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it works fine here in the codepen example

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/meuequalsd/pen/GjZyXN)

**Please verify if jquery is loaded and Owl js file should be included after jquery**

Similar to this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css" />
```

Comment: Accept the answer as correct one if your problem is solved. It might help someone else too. Thanks

Comment: the problem is owl carousel js file was too old...so that i was stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be like below.

```
<div class="sliderImgs">
        <div class="item"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img/man.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="img/slider.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: item div not necessary but i have tried but still i am getting problem. and thanx for helping.